# How to assign model validation error to a key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

In the same way that you can add a model validation within the controller:

```
ModelState.AddValidationError([KEY], "This is an error message")
```

Can I add the error within my model validation using annotations?

```
// For demonstration purposes only
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This is an error message"), AddErrorMessageToKey = [KEY]]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Sometimes it's not always appropriate to add the error message to a particular property.  In my application I wish to only show one error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this helper with every property in viewpage .

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")
```

And in controller:

```
Use TempData in the ActionResult 


TempData["CustomError"] = "This is an error message";
```